# SSIS execution fails when attempting to connect on remote server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Need some help with a SSIS package I'm creating. So here's what I've done up until now.

I have a DTSX that has a Script Component in a Data Flow that references an assembly where I have all my logic to connect to a remote server using entity framework and retrieve some records from a table.

All my unit and integration tests on that assembly work fine. Unfortunately after deploying the package to Server A and running it with a SQL Agent Job, it gives an error when executing the script component indicating that it cannot find the SQL instance I'm looking for. Same result if I try to execute manually the package.

I've already made sure that the servers can communicate. I've created a console app using that assembly and it works fine, I've made ping requests to the remote server and it's ok, I've connected to that server using SQL Management Studio, I've even added the remote server as a linked server on server A and was able to execute a query.

Last attempt I made was creating a SQL Agent Job that run my test console app, and the result is OK too. I did this to make sure that the user that invokes the console is the same that invokes the DTSX.

I'm really getting out of ideas so if anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Comment: can you see the SSIS logs? If so, what are some of the errors you are seeing in the output. Also, how did you configure the SQL Connection auth for EF? I suspect that this is a permission issue.

Comment: it's getting the connection string from the DTSexec config file. The exact error I'm getting is "Error Locating Server/Instance Specified". In the connection string I've set a valid user and password so it's not trying to do Integrated Security. I also thought that it was permissions that's why I've tried to run my console test app using a Agent job too, but that work's ok. DTSX not.

Comment: The error message is specifically stating that it cannot find the server.  Please check the spelling of the server and instance name in the config file.  You can try using "\\" instead of "\" which might be getting converted someplace.  Makes sure the port is correct if you are not using the default port.  Turn on SQL browser on the target server if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found what was wrong. I was missing some configurations that needed to be addes to IServerExec instead of dtshost config file.  Unfortunately the error message wasn't clear enough.